# django database sqlite3 "no such a column" error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-modeladmin

time to time i am facing "`no such a column`" error during django backend, django-admin development. when i face this issue, i cannot solve it. so that;

1. i detele `db.sqllite3` database file in my project location.
2. i delete migrations files in application folder  `/djangioapp/migrations/`
3. i run `makemigrations`, `migrate` and `createsuperuser` commands.

i face with this error when i make changes on my Model. even more, i updated my model, i run makemigrations and migrate commands and i got this error `no such a column` when i try to access /admin in my djnago project.

actually, after making migrations with `makemigrations` and `migrate`; i see the changes in `0001_initial.py` file but it does not apply in database.

is there any practical solution for "`no such a column`" error?

i face with this error when i make changes on my Model. even more, i updated my model, i run makemigrations and migrate commands and i got this error `no such a column` when i try to access /admin in my djnago project.

actually, after making migrations with `makemigrations` and `migrate`; i see the changes in `0001_initial.py` file but it does not apply in database.

Answer (score 0):

Try This commands

```bash
- python manage.py makemigrations your_app_name
- python manage.py migrate
- python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: These commands do not work for me. I am still developing the application, so that I deleted db completely and created again. Still the issue remain.